# which django cache backend to use?

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I been using cmemcache + memcache for a while with positive results.

However cmemcache lately not tagging along well and I also found that it's now recommended. I have now installed python-memcached and its working well. As I have decided to change would like to try some other cache back end any recommendation.

I have also came across pylibmc and python-libmemcached any other??

Have anyone tried nginx memcache module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only cmemcache and python-memcached are supported by the Django memcached backend. I don't have experience with either of the two libraries you mentioned, but if you want to use them you will need to write a new cache backend.

The nginx memcached module is something completely different. It doesn't really seem like it would work well with Django's caching, but it might with enough hacking. At any rate, I wouldn't use it, since it is much better if you control what gets cached and retrieved from cache from the Python side.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As for the nginx I came across this which sounded interesting (but I don't completely understand it yet)

http://www.igvita.com/2008/02/11/nginx-and-memcached-a-400-boost/

there is also a django implementation of the above..

http://weichhold.com/2008/09/12/django-nginx-memcached-the-dynamic-trio/

I am tempted to give it a try to see what's this all about.

Comment: I was going to suggest something like the latter post, where Django inserts into the key and Nginx retrieves it, but the Nginx docs weren't quite as clear about how to handle cache misses.